# C# run a SQL Server procedure periodically (every 1 mins)

Tags: c#, sql-server, timer

I need to periodically call a SQL Server stored procedure, when my program runs, it does not display error or exception, and at beginning everything is ok, the only problem is as time elapse, program will suddenly stop, and does not do anything.

Here is my code. First, I'm using `System.Timer` to make it run every minute

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Timer myTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(Callback, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
}
```

Then, in function `callback`, I call my SQL Server stored procedure and write results to a txt file

```
public void Callback(object state)
{
   try
   {
      DataTable dt = null;
      sp_select_today_sum_ASRACD_fromMera_by_Vendor(strFrom, strTo, strCustomer, strAreaPrefix, ref dt);

      string strJJTEL_ASR = null;
      string strJJTEL_ACD = null;

      string strARCA_ASR = null;
      string strARCA_ACD = null;

      string strSHINETOWN_ASR = null;
      string strSHINETOWN_ACD = null;

      if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
         foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) // Loop over the rows.
         {
             if (row["vendor"].ToString() == "01.2352")      
             {
                strJJTEL_ASR = row["ASR"].ToString();
                strJJTEL_ACD = row["ACD"].ToString();
             }

             if (row["vendor"].ToString() == "01.2208")    
             {
                strARCA_ASR = row["ASR"].ToString();
                strARCA_ACD = row["ACD"].ToString();
             }

             if (row["vendor"].ToString() == "01.2238")       
             {
                strSHINETOWN_ASR = row["ASR"].ToString();
                strSHINETOWN_ACD = row["ACD"].ToString();
             }
          }
       }

       string str_report = null;

       str_report = " at " + strTo + " ,  JJtel 's ASR is " + strJJTEL_ASR + " and ACD is " + strJJTEL_ACD + "\r\n"
       + " ARCA 's ASR is " + strARCA_ASR + " and ACD is " + strARCA_ACD + "\r\n"
       + " SHINETOWN 's ASR is " + strSHINETOWN_ASR + " and ACD is " + strSHINETOWN_ACD + "\r\n";

       File.AppendAllText(strCurrentPath + @"\log.txt", str_report);
   }
   catch (Exception tep)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(tep.Message);
   }
}
```

And this is the function which really calls the SQL Server stored procedure:

```
public  void sp_select_today_sum_ASRACD_fromMera_by_Vendor(string timeFrom, string timeTo, string customer, string areaPrefix, ref DataTable dt)
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    SqlConnection conn = null;

    conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=myDatasource;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=myPassword;Connect Timeout=0");
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_select_today_sum_ASRACD_fromMera_by_Vendor", conn);
    sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 120;

    try
    {
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@timeFrom", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@timeFrom"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@timeFrom"].Value = timeFrom;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@timeTo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@timeTo"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@timeTo"].Value = timeTo;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@customer", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@customer"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@customer"].Value = customer;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@areaPrefix", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@areaPrefix"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@areaPrefix"].Value = areaPrefix;

        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
           conn.Open();

        reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader != null)
        {
           dt.Load(reader);
        }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        File.AppendAllText(strCurrentPath + @"\log.txt", ex.Message);
     }
     finally
     {
        if (reader != null)
           reader.Dispose();

        sqlCmd.Dispose();

        if (conn != null)
        {
           conn.Close();
           conn.Dispose();
        }
     }
}
```

My output looks like this :

```
now enter key time , start query at 2014/1/2 17:27:26 with fromTime = 20140101000000 and toTime= 20140101010000
 at 20140101010000 ,  JJtel 's ASR is 0.276214 and ACD is 7.563518
 ARCA 's ASR is 0.284987 and ACD is 4.674375
 SHINETOWN 's ASR is 0.233160 and ACD is 4.081777
now enter key time , start query at 2014/1/2 17:28:13 with fromTime = 20140101010000 and toTime= 20140101020000
 at 20140101020000 ,  JJtel 's ASR is 0.097701 and ACD is 14.808235
 ARCA 's ASR is 0.303571 and ACD is 9.226666
 SHINETOWN 's ASR is 0.318181 and ACD is 10.693928
now enter key time , start query at 2014/1/2 17:29:13 with fromTime = 20140101020000 and toTime= 20140101030000
 at 20140101030000 ,  JJtel 's ASR is 0.259740 and ACD is 6.896000
 ARCA 's ASR is 0.240506 and ACD is 14.531578
 SHINETOWN 's ASR is 0.216216 and ACD is 12.030000
now enter key time , start query at 2014/1/2 17:30:14 with fromTime = 20140101030000 and toTime= 20140101040000
 at 20140101040000 ,  JJtel 's ASR is 0.150000 and ACD is 6.846666
 ARCA 's ASR is 0.243243 and ACD is 4.073333
 SHINETOWN 's ASR is 0.181818 and ACD is 0.747500
now enter key time , start query at 2014/1/2 17:31:14 with fromTime = 20140101040000 and toTime= 20140101050000
 at 20140101050000 ,  JJtel 's ASR is 0.083333 and ACD is 11.570000
 ARCA 's ASR is 0.269230 and ACD is 12.494285
 SHINETOWN 's ASR is 0.133333 and ACD is 0.670000
now enter key time , start query at 2014/1/2 17:32:21 with fromTime = 20140101050000 and toTime= 20140101060000
 at 20140101060000 ,  JJtel 's ASR is 0.157894 and ACD is 5.681666
 ARCA 's ASR is 0.375000 and ACD is 3.677333
 SHINETOWN 's ASR is 0.285714 and ACD is 5.483333
now enter key time , start query at 2014/1/2 17:33:14 with fromTime = 20140101060000 and toTime= 20140101070000
 at 20140101070000 ,  JJtel 's ASR is 0.304347 and ACD is 5.135428
 ARCA 's ASR is 0.264957 and ACD is 4.304193
 SHINETOWN 's ASR is 0.355932 and ACD is 5.980476
now enter key time , start query at 2014/1/2 17:34:14 with fromTime = 20140101070000 and toTime= 20140101080000
 at 20140101080000 ,  JJtel 's ASR is 0.280936 and ACD is 5.052500
 ARCA 's ASR is 0.308219 and ACD is 5.374777
 SHINETOWN 's ASR is 0.214285 and ACD is 2.462424
now enter key time , start query at 2014/1/2 17:35:14 with fromTime = 20140101080000 and toTime= 20140101090000
 at 20140101090000 ,  JJtel 's ASR is 0.315533 and ACD is 5.821000
 ARCA 's ASR is 0.339805 and ACD is 4.952142
 SHINETOWN 's ASR is 0.268867 and ACD is 4.965438
now enter key time , start query at 2014/1/2 17:36:16 with fromTime = 20140101090000 and toTime= 20140101100000
 at 20140101100000 ,  JJtel 's ASR is 0.326498 and ACD is 4.864444
 ARCA 's ASR is 0.346666 and ACD is 6.922115
 SHINETOWN 's ASR is 0.312500 and ACD is 8.728500
```

Please notice the last record, it show start at 17:36:16, but from that time, no result is got anymore, seems program is down, but no any error or exception  occur, could anyone tell me what is the reason?

Comment: in `sp_select_today_sum_ASRACD_fromMera_by_Vendor` you are logging exceptions to a log file. Have you checked that file? Because any exception in that function will not stop the program running since you are not re-throwing it.

Comment: You should avoid naming stored procedures with an `sp_` prefix - it's reserved for Microsoft's system procedures, there are funky lookup rules, and in the event of a conflict, the MS one will win. Also, why are you not using something that already does scheduling, e.g. SQL Server agent or even Windows Scheduler. Finally, to your problem, it's likely that your timer gets GCed.

Comment: So if the 120 second timeout is reached because Sql Server is busy and is queing your request etc you would recieve no results.

Comment: By the way threads are really intended for short-lived tasks, not long running ones like you are using it for. There is the potential that your task (with default priority) is being queued for more important tasks to execute first. Try looking into using the cache instead, and sets it's priority to never be removed.

Comment: very strange , when i change my code ,  do not use System.Threading.Timer , and  just put operate code in a simple while(true)   loop ,  then in the loop  Thread.Sleep(60000) , which equal 1 minute , the program do not stop anymore , it seems problem is not on  sql server side.